# How do i get prettier to be more pretty in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

This has been driving me wild for a little while here and i can't figure it out.
I have tried setting my `prettier.printWidth` to 160 or 400 but it makes no difference. My environment is Vscode with prettier/vetur for Vue.
I can use `// prettier-ignore` above the code but that's not a solution.

How i want it to look:

```
 // prettier-ignore
    if(!this.dataFields.some((field) => this.item.field && field.text === this.item.field)) {
      // Find the field in the all fields list
      const foundField = this.allDataFields.find((field) => field.text === this.item.field)
```

How it actually looks:

```
 if (
      !this.dataFields.some(
        (field) => this.item.field && field.text === this.item.field
      )
    ) {
      // Find the field in the all fields list
      const foundField = this.allDataFields.find(
        (field) => field.text === this.item.field
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prettier has very few configuration options [by design](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). It offers a small amount of control concerning [multi-line objects](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#multi-line-objects), but in the end it it designed to take the decision on how to style certain code elements off the developers.

So the only options I see here are:

1. Accept Prettier's suggestions, lean back and be relieved that you never have to think or discuss about code styling again.

OR

2. Don't use Prettier.

Comment: Yeah this is what I feared.